# What are the outputs of a combo box in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

If I put a list of cells as the 'Input range' through the [format control window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOrqr.png) of my Combo Box I seem to get the position (an integer starting from 1) of the selected item in the range as output. Is this the default and is there a way to change the output? If it helps I'm using Excel on Mac. Thanks!

Comment: Not very clearly about your problem. Did you want to use the dynamic range?